# Determining the correct test for experiment design

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures, manova

I'm trying to figure out the right test to use for my experimental design, I was hoping someone here could help. Here's the structure:

- Two independent variables, IV1 and IV2. IV1 has 3 levels, IV2 has 5 levels, for 15 total
  conditions.
- Every human subject completes 15 trials, one in each of the 15 conditions
  (i.e. every subject does every combination of IV1 and IV2).
- For each trial, 4 dependent variables are recorded. DV1 and DV2 are
  likely to be correlated (response time and accuracy on a primary
  task), and DV3 and DV4 are likely to be correlated (response time and
  accuracy on a secondary task).
- I'm trying to test for interaction effects of IV1 and IV2, on each of the pairs of DVs.

Initially, I was thinking of doing this as a two-factor repeated-measures ANOVA, and doing one of those for each DV. But then I started thinking abouut MANOVA, since some of the DVs are correlated. Maybe two MANOVAs, one for DV1/DV2 and one for DV3/DV4? I'm not sure if you can use MANOVA for repeated-measures (fully within-subject, no between-subject) designs though, because I think one of the assumptions is that the observations are fully independent.

Bonus points if anyone can explain how to do the correct test in SPSS.